# htaccess file works in apache 2.2 but not in apache 2.4 - aws beanstalk hosted

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to make this `.htaccess` file work in Apache 2.4. It seems Apache 2.4 does not like

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

I changed that to

```
  <FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|psd|log|sh|crt|gitignore|md)$">
          Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
```

Here are some errors I have seen so far implementing it:

> ```
> AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh)
> AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
> ```

And here is the `.htaccess` file I am trying to make work in Apache 2.4. Can you spot anything else Apache 2.4 would not like ?

```
    Options -Indexes
    
    <FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|psd|log|sh|crt|gitignore|md)$">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
    <Files 8fjfsuUhhhhh8/*>
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files backups/*>
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files stats/*>
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files icons/*>
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files error/*>
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files logs/*>
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files git/*>
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .git/*>
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ https://blog.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
    
        # Old Site Redirects
        RewriteRule ^retailers($|/$) /merchants/ [R=301,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^faqs($|/) /FAQ/ [R=301,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^contact($|/) /contact-us/ [R=301,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^login($|/) /customer-login/ [R=301,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^bank-vision($|/) /FAQ/ [R=301,NC,L]
    
        # New Website Proxying
        # Handle Request to index
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\ .*
        RewriteRule . http://mysite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ [P]
    
        # Handle all the named pages
        RewriteRule ^(merchants|how-it-works|shop-directory|contact-us|terms-of-use|privacy-policy|complaints-policy|careers|FAQ|error)($|/) http://mysite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/$1$2 [P]
    
        # Handle the various static elements
        RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ http://mysite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/static/$1 [P]
        RewriteRule ^page-data/(.*)$ http://mysite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/page-data/$1 [P]
        RewriteRule ^([^\/]*).js$ http://mysite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/$1.js [P]
        RewriteRule ^icons-(.*)/(.*)\.(png|jpg)$ http://mysite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/icons-$1/$2.$3 [P]
    
        # Handle request to homepage with get parameters
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\?utm_source=([^\s&]+)
        RewriteRule . http://mysite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ [P]
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\?ref=([^\s&]+)
        RewriteRule . http://mysite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ [P]
    
        # Legacy Platform stuff
        RewriteRule ^(frontend/process/process/components|admin-lf7/ui/ajax|frontend/ajax|8fjfsuUFks988/cron)($|/) - [L]
        RewriteRule ^rt8aglCo7XfQOxxQH2mTDZw45675675675567P27da4t1T1yJIB5Be58ih /admin.php [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]
        RewriteRule .*\.php$ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

When I use this `.htaccess` file from AWS beanstalk examples I can see the site ok :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: None of your `<Files>` directives look as if they would match anything? eg. What are you expecting `<Files logs/*>` to match? The `<Files>` directive matches _filenames_ only, not file-paths. And some of those mod_rewrite directives don't look as if they are doing what you think they are doing? I think some of the issues you may be having are just differences in the server config, rather than differences between Apache 2.2 and 2.4 per se. (?) Your original directives assume that the `DirectoryIndex` is set correctly, but the later `.htaccess` file avoids the need for this.

Comment: @MrWhite I checked the `<Files>` directives and they match for the directory but not the files in the directory. I took out all the mod_rewrite directives referring to s3 buckets and was able to get the site to load.

Answer (score 2):

`Order Allow,Deny Deny from all` is backward compatible with Apache 2.4, so you should be fine with old config.

The error `AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh)`
is actually attempt to exploit your server and your apache correctly denyes that.

Do you test that FilesMatch properly ? like trying to access: *yourpage.com/.htaccess* ? As result you should see in log your second "error" `AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/` which means your .htaccess and the FilesMatch within works as should

Comment: "`Order Allow,Deny Deny from all` is backward compatible with Apache 2.4" - Well, kind of. These directives have been moved to mod_access_compat (and formerly deprecated). This module is now an "Extension" (as opposed to a "Base" module) and consequently is not enabled by default. On AWS they would likely need to explicitly enable this module (or convert the directives to use mod_authz_host instead - which would be preferable).

Comment: The second "error" indicates a request to `/var/www/html/` (which looks like it could be the document root) is blocked, not `.htaccess`. This could result from a conflict between old and new access control directives.

Comment: @MrWhite you are right, my answer is wrong, would like to delete it but your comments are on point. maybe you could repost all your comments as an answer